# sql how to order by whether a string is found within a column?

Tags: sql, postgresql

so I aggregrate some strings (with either `array_agg` or `string_agg`) and put it in a new column.

I then want to:

```
order by ("searchString" in columnName)
```

However, it appears "in" is a keyword only working in where clauses. What should I use instead?

edit:

got it to work using bool_or

just used select bool_or(columnName = 'keyword') from and then ordered by the new column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `bool_or()` assuming you want an exact match:

```
order by bool_or(col = <search_string>)
```

If you want a partial match, you can use `like` or regular expressions instead.

Comment: this seems to be the right answer, but I can't seem to get it to work yet. It recognizes the idx column, but not the keywords column

select idx, array_agg(keyword) as keywords

can I not reference an alias inside bool_or?

Comment: @JamesJoshuaStreet . . . `having bool_or(keyword = ?)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`position()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html):

```
order by position('searchString' in columnName)
```

but if `columnName` is comma delimited:

```
order by position(',searchString,' in concat(',', columnName, ','))
```

`position()` returns 0 if the `'searchString'` is not found inside `columnName`.
In this case maybe you need a case statement:

```
order by case position(',searchString,' in concat(',', columnName, ',')) 
  when 0 then 9999 -- or any other large number
  else position(',searchString,' in concat(',', columnName, ','))
end
```